# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: IN Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am making a phone number validation with the country code in the angular application. As I am new to this topic I got some error and I need some help I followed "ngx-intl-tel-input" International Telephone Input and the Link is "
and the documentation available here [documentation](https://webcat12345.github.io/ngx-intl-tel-input/overview.html)

```css
h2 {
    margin: 40px 10px;
  }
  
  .avatar {
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 10px solid white;
  }
  
  .marquee {
    background: #ff5d5d;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .marquee h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-family: 'Baloo', cursive;
  }
  
  span {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Standard Usage</h2>
      <ngx-intl-tel-input [(value)]="phone_number_standard" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
      <span>Phone number : </span>{{phone_number_standard}} 
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Preferred Countries</h2>
      <!-- <ngx-intl-tel-input [(value)]="phone_number" [preferredCountries]="phone_number_preferred"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
      <span>Phone number : </span>{{phone_number}} -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
error Log`core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
```

Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-intl-tel-input'.
1. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

### Standard Usage

][(value)]="phone_number_standard" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries">
   "): ng:///CountryCodePageModule/CountryCodePage.html@18:26
Can't bind to 'preferredCountries' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-intl-tel-input'.
1. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is an Angular component and it has 'preferredCountries' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ntainer">

### Standard Usage

][preferredCountries]="preferredCountries">
      Phone number : {{p"): ng:///CountryCodePageModule/CountryCodePage.html@18:60
'ngx-intl-tel-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

### Standard Usage

[ERROR ->]

### Standard Usage

][(value)]="phone_number_standard" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries">
   "): ng:///CountryCodePageModule/CountryCodePage.html@18:26
Can't bind to 'preferredCountries' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-intl-tel-input'.
1. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is an Angular component and it has 'preferredCountries' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ntainer">

### Standard Usage

][preferredCountries]="preferredCountries">
      Phone number : {{p"): ng:///CountryCodePageModule/CountryCodePage.html@18:60
'ngx-intl-tel-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-intl-tel-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

### Standard Usage

[ERROR ->])
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:23948)
    at compiler.js:23858
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23857)
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14830)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:24018)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:24005)
    at compiler.js:23948
    at Set.forEach ()
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:23948)
    at compiler.js:23858
    at Object.then (compiler.js:1012)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:23857)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)`

Comment: Did you import both BsDropdownModule and NgxIntlTelInputModule as described [here](https://webcat12345.github.io/ngx-intl-tel-input/)?

Comment: It should be imported in `CountryCodePageModule`

Comment: Yes I added both